# What is the C# equivalent of: printf("%s", " ");?

Tags: c#, c

I'm looking at a program that was written in C and I need to write it in C#.

What is the C# equivalent of this whole line?:

```
printf("%s", " ");
```

Comment: Console.Write("{0}", " ");  Google "c# composite formatting" for info.

Comment: Specify for the application type like Console, Windows, Web, etc. For console, you can use Console.WriteLine(" ");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use C# 6, you could use string interpolation, and go like this.

```
Console.WriteLine($"{variableName} text");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use it for print data. same function can use for print all data type in C#

```
 Console.WriteLine(variableName);
```